# kill process if it is idle for 30 mins

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix, awk

I am trying to put a script which will run in back ground to check process and if it is idle for 30 mins then kill

the grep i want to use is

```
"/usr/bin/python ./utt.py --type=issuer --datafile="
```

so far i have put the code as below , iam stuck at the end how to compare the time and kill  . i was able to get process time and system time .how to compare and kill if the process is idle for 30 mins.

```
ps -auxw | grep "/usr/bin/python ./utt.py --type=issuer --datafile=" | awk '{Time=strftime("%H:%M", systime());print $2,$9,Time ;if($9<Time) kill -9 $2"}'
```

thanks for you help

Comment: `start time` (or `elapsed time`) is NOT `idle time`

Comment: How about just killing it after 30 minutes whether it's idle or not? You can easily do that with `timeout`

Comment: Does the process produce logs at execution?  You could check the last time the file was written to.